# What is the best practice in creating apple-app-site-association file in aem

Tags: ios, aem, ios-universal-app

What is the industry practice in generating apple-app-site-association file in AEM?

1. Write a sling servlet that will generate the JSON (with env specific entries)
2. Create static jsons  (e.g. "apple-app-site-association.prod.json" and "apple-app-site-association.qa.json") and write Apache rewrite rules to pick right file based of env.

We have environment specific requirement to populate different appId for QA, UAT and Prod. And the appId is dynamic potential to change in future. With this, what is the suggested approach to publish the json file?

Or is there a better option that we are not foreseeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished this with option 1. Created a sling servlet generating the json. Reason is, the appId is dynamic (different for QA, QP and Prod) and this appId is being populated as meta tag on all templates. Hence created a sling servlet, added appId as component property and referenced from templates.

Answer (score 0):

To Support Universal Links apple-app-site-association file 
Here fully In Details Documentation of apple-app-site-association
[Please refers this.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)

As per Apple developer portal 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. question is not how to create. Question is what is the best practice to create on AEM as there are 2 options to do.